# Perl's "Switch" grabs a 'case' string inside a HERE document and gets confused?

Tags: perl

I have a little Perl code, with a HERE document. Inside the HERE document's text, there is embedded the keyword *case*. This seems to unnerve the [Switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Switch.html) statement mightily. Am I crazy?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;  # Meaning "This lexical scope (i.e. file) contains utf8"

use Switch;

sub printUsage {
   print STDERR << "HERE";

                       +
  --rollback           | - In case of "--reallydo", perform a ROLLBACK instead of a COMMIT at
                       |   transaction end.
                       + 
HERE
}
```

Running this in Perl 5.16 gives:

```
Bad case statement (invalid case value?) near avo2.pl line 13
```

i.e. `In case of` isn't appreciated "here", literally. Some bug? Should I raise this at the [Perl bug tracker](https://rt.perl.org/Public/)?

Comment: Switch is a source filter, which means it must parse the Perl code that follows itself. An impossible feat, so it doesn't really actually try. You get errors such as the one you describe, and they can be very hard to debug. Avoid Switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't `use Switch` if you can possibly avoid it, it's a source filter and you have found one of the bugs lurking in it's depths. given()/when() would be better, but that has problems and is now marked as experimental. If you want the equivalent of a case statement try

```
for ($test_this) {
    if ( ! /\D/ ) {
        say 'is numbers';
        last;
    }
    if ( $_ eq 'exit' ) {
        say 'exit found';
        last;
    }
    if (/^\p{Lu}/) {
        say 'Upper case letter';
        last;
    }
    # Default option
    say 'Default';
    last;
}
```

Comment: Or use a dispatch table if viable.